# How to pass any Go variable into a C function that accepts a void *?

Tags: c, go, cgo

I have the following function `set` in `C`:

```
void set(void *data)
{
    // do some work with data (which points to a Go variable)
}
```

Now, in `Go` I need to have a function that accepts any variable as a parameter and calls the `C` function `set` passing this parameter to it. How can I do this? Can we do it by having the `Go` function accepting a parameter like `data interface{}`, call `unsafe.Pointer` passing this parameter, and then call the `C` function with the result of `unsafe.Pointer`?

Comment: If the parameter is of type `interface{}`, then you have a Go interface Value, which is not a pointer. If you want pass a pointer to C, you need to have a pointer. I suggest you first read the docs in detail, since passing Go pointers to C has a lot of restrictions and is easy to get wrong: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo#hdr-Passing_pointers

Comment: @JimB: thanks for the link. I'm not sure how to proceed with this. Would you mind to post an answer? Thanks!

Comment: There's not much I can say other than `unsafe.Pointer` is the rough equivalent to `void*`. There's not enough information here to formulate any sort of answer.

Comment: @JimB: Let's imagine that you have a `Go` variable `data [2][3] int32`, how would you implement a `Go` function called `MyFunc` such that when calling it like `MyFunc(data)` it calls function `C` function `set` passing the address of `data` to it?

Comment: since `void*` is passed in as an `unsafe.Pointer`, you would call `C.set(unsafe.Pointer(&data))`

Comment: Nice! But how to pass `data` when calling `Go` function `MyFunc` (which by the way `data` could be of any data type)? Moreover, what would be the function protoype of `MyFunc`? Thanks!

Comment: That requires more context since you would normally have a function with the type defines, but you could technically use `reflect` to get a pointer from an interface. You could also accept `unsafe.Pointer` at the function call, but you have to be much more careful of the data lifecycle in that case.

Comment: Would you mind to post a solution using `reflect`? I will be glad to accept the answer - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are following the constraints detailed in the [passing pointers](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo#hdr-Passing_pointers) section of the CGO documentation, you can create a Go wrapper function accepting an empty interface argument, and extract the pointer value using `reflect`.

```
func Set(i interface{}) {
    C.set(unsafe.Pointer(reflect.ValueOf(i).Pointer()))
}
```